# Trying to run django script as standalone - models error

Tags: django

I am using django installed via cookiecutter(running inside virtualenv). On top of the file I try to setup django env. like this:

```
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.append('/vagrant/my_project/my_project/')    
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')
django.setup()
from models import KeyO # This one loads models.py from the same directory.
```

models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from decimal import Decimal
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField    

class KeyO(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField('Keyword', max_length=1000, unique=True)
    ...
```

And here is the error:

> RuntimeError: Model class models.KeyO doesn't declare an explicit
>   app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

I didn't modify apps.py and my settings file loads this app at the end. Any ideas?

Note: Using py3.5 and django 1.10 dev

Edit:

local settings: https://gist.github.com/daniel1943/6148f27e157bdb251666
common(main settings): https://gist.github.com/daniel1943/76c46fcfaaa996c9fd66

Comment: Can you add your settings.py file in your original question? I want to check it.

Comment: Added both to original question.

Comment: I've run into the same problem here... I think its Django 1.9 dev though. Can't get it to see config.settings.local

Answer (score 2):

*So here is the solution:*

Instead of importing model with:

```
from models import KeyO
```

Do it like:

```
from myapp.models import KeyO
```

And the entire code to run standalone django 1.9+ scripts:

```
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.append("/media/sf_VM_desktop/myproject/") #path to your settings file  
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
django.setup()

from keywords.models import KW
```